# Does a windows form have anything to uniquely identify it?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework

I have a bunch of forms that I need to put in a list and know if the form is already in there.

For reasons not relevant to this question, I cannot actually have a reference to the form in the list.

Is there a ID or Guid that is on a winform that I could use?  Or should I just add a Guid to all my forms?

Note that this is Compact Framework.  So the "ID" needs to be available in the .NETCF 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window handle (`hWnd`) should do the trick. Look for the `Handle` property of your forms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any ID present in a winform. Thus I believe your approach of having a GUID for each form instance could be a viable solution. Your form is just a class, an object with properties, I don't see a particular reason why MS would of added an ID to identify a particular form, since this is really a specific requirement, just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Compact Framework. I would look for the **`Form.Tag`** property. If there is one, use it. This property is meant to be used for programmer's will.

Otherwise, you could just generalize a FormBase class from which your other forms would inherit. Put in it the Guid property so that you will access it to verify a form's existance in the list.

Besides, the `Contains` method takes an object as an argument, so passing an instance of your expected form would tell you whether your form is in the list. Although this might be a bit overkill, since you have to instantiate your form to verify its existance into the list.

Another way around is the use of a `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`, where you can add the name of a form for the TKey part of the dictionary, and your form as for the TValue.

Answer (score 0):

Form.Name (inherited from Control) can also do the trick.